# jmwidget set indicator value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I really enjoy this set of widgets: http://www.jmwidgets.com/index.php/docs/widgets/hmiindicator/

However, I need to set the value of an indicator at initialize (or later on page update) using  a value, rather than linking it to another value (although I could do this through a dummy element if I had to I suppose).

I can't, no matter what I've tried, get it to work. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uLuZQ/39/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>HMI Indicator Example</title>

    <!-- JMWidgets styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base/jmwidgets-0.8.0.base.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jmwidgets-0.8.0.allstyles.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery classes -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JMWidget classes -->
<script src="js/jmwidgets-0.8.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("#ind1").hmiIndicator( {colors:['red','yellow','green'],value:1} );    
            var val= $("#ind1").hmiIndicator( 'option','value' ); 
            alert(val)
});
</script>
</head>
<body id="page1">

<div id="ind1" style="width:150px; height:150px"></div>
<br />

</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me what I'm stupidly missing. The documentation seems pretty clear, but I can't get it to work at initialize or using setter.

Thanks,
C